# Cant get jQuery methods to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it when I select html elements using .get(i) or similar methods, I am unable to use methods on those elements like the .removeClass() or .html().

I would think that the code below is perfectly valid, yet neither lines work. What do I need to do to apply jQuery methods to an element based on its ordinal index in the DOM?

```
($('li').get(0)).removeClass('yourClass');
$('li')[0].addClass('myClass');
```

Here is an example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/KcNWy/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/get):
*The .get() method grants us access to the **DOM nodes** underlying each jQuery object.*

You can DOM object into jQuery object again: `$($('li').get(0))`. Or, better yet, use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq): `$('li').eq(0)`.

And also a debugging hint. You can use in firefox/chrome/safari `console.log(myObject)` to see what's actually returned.

Answer (score 1):

The [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method passes back the DOM object

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

Try this instead:

```
$("li:eq(" + 0 + ")").removeClass("yourClass")
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KcNWy/6/